# There is a problem when using nesting in i18next

Tags: node.js, internationalization, translation, i18next

I am using i18next in a node application and there is a problem when I am using nesting.

I have the following:

```json
{
  "fields": {
    "name": "Name"
  },
  "validations": {
    "required": "{{field}} is required"
  },
  "validations-fields": {
    "name": {
      "required": "$t(validations:required, {\"field\": \"$t(fields:name)\"})"
    }
  }
}
```

When I do the following:

```js
t("en", "name.required", { ns: "validations-fields" }
```

I get the following:

```js
{{field}} is required\"})
```

It doesn't make any sense to me. I should get "Name is required".

If I put the following it works:

```json
{
  "validations": {
    "required": "{{field}} is required"
  },
  "validations-fields": {
    "name": {
      "required": "$t(validations:required, {\"field\": \"Name\"})"
    }
  }
}
```

However, that is not how I want to do it.